# How to use LongPressDraggable in ListView on Flutter

Tags: flutter, drag-and-drop, flutter-listview

I have a list of elements (listview widget) that can be moved to a target, (in the example I don't include the target to simplify, my question is in the listview). Each item in the list is a **LongPressDraggable**.

My problem is that when touching an element of the list, if the finger moves minimally, almost imperceptibly, then the longpress event does not fire, you have to lift your finger again and touch the element again.

In the **LongPressDraggable** I am setting the property `delay: const Duration(milliseconds: 50)`, by default it has 500 ms and with this I have improved the user experience somewhat.

My question is the following: Is there any way to specify a clearance to the listview, that is, a minimum movement so that after that clearance it launches the scroll event and while not?

This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp2());
}

class MyApp2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp2({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      scrollBehavior: const MaterialScrollBehavior().copyWith(
          dragDevices: {PointerDeviceKind.mouse, PointerDeviceKind.touch}),
      title: 'ListView',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: getBody(context),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getBody(BuildContext context) {
    var list = <Widget>[];
    list.add(Container(height: 50, width: 100, color: Colors.black));
    list.add(Container(height: 50, width: 100, color: Colors.amber));
    list.add(Container(
        height: 50, width: 100, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 241, 150, 143)));
    list.add(Container(height: 50, width: 100, color: Colors.blue));
    list.add(Container(height: 50, width: 100, color: Colors.pink));
    list.add(Container(height: 50, width: 100, color: Colors.blueAccent));

    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const SizedBox(
          width: 10,
        ),
        
        SizedBox(
          width: 100,
          height: 200,
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: list.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                  child: LongPressDraggable<Widget>(
                      delay: const Duration(milliseconds: 50)
                      data: list[index],
                      feedback: AnimatedScale(
                          duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                          scale: 1.25,
                          child: list[index]),
                      childWhenDragging:
                          Opacity(opacity: 0.5, child: list[index]),
                      child: list[index]),
                );
              }),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include sample code-snippet that will you;ve tried so far and reproduce the error ?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, you are right, I have already edited the question. thank you

Comment: Maybe you like ReordableListView

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, I really need to move from one place to another, it is not ordering the list itself. In the example I have not put the target section to simplify the code. thanks